# Float in bash using awk

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

This is just an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to do. Basically I have script that has to execute code in an `if` statement depending on the version of MySQL. To test I've got this below. I know bash won't do floats so I was going to use `awk`. Can anyone help to make this work?

```
#!/bin/bash

var=5.5
mysqlV=5.6

if awk '{print $var > $mysqlV}'; then
result=1
else
result=0
echo $result
fi
```

Comment: Version numbers are not, in general, floating-point values. They are multiple integers joined by periods, for example 5.6.1.

Comment: I know I have a variable that truncates it `MYSQL_VER=$(mysql -V | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -c-3)`

Answer (score 4):

To compare floats with awk, bash and different return codes:

```
var="5.5"
mysqlV="5.6"

if awk -v var="$var" -v mysqlV="$mysqlV" 'BEGIN{if (var>mysqlV) exit 0; else exit 1}'; then
  echo "larger"
else
  echo "smaller"
fi
```

Output:

```
smaller
```

---

Shorter version:

```
if awk -v var="$var" -v mysqlV="$mysqlV" 'BEGIN{exit(var>mysqlV)?0:1}'; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using awk you could use the bash calculator ([bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)) in the following way:

```
var=5.5
mysqlV=5.6

a=`echo $var'>'$mysqlV | bc -l`

echo $a
> 0

var=5.8
a=`echo $var'>'$mysqlV | bc -l`

echo $a
> 1
```